# how do you check when a new youtube video is uploaded on a specific channel

Tags: javascript, youtube

So I was wandering if there is a way in JS to check when a youtube video is uploaded on a specific channel via the channnel name! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of anything else but the plain old Web Controlling with the help of [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). You might need to code and design every bit of the action that needs to be done in order to perform what you require.

For example, if you need to know if a new video is uploaded on a youtube channel, you need to, roughly, follow the following steps:

1. Design a function that accepts the channel name as an argument.
2. Work with Selenium to do the rest of the things, such as, opening the browser, hitting the URL (www.youtube.com/channel/{channel-url}/videos)
3. Inspect the selector of the div or any HTML tag that contains the information about the videos.
4. Keep track of the number of videos at a given time
5. Schedule the program to run after a certain period of time and compare the count of videos previously extracted with the latest one
6. If the count is greater, send an email (or notify the user as you like)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Youtube API docs

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

Your app should login the Google Account using OAuth

Then using the API subscribe to the channel push notifications.

There will be subtle differences if your app is either node or browser based.

Comment: some Google services have an option to connect to the API with a service key, i.e. , you wouldn't need a manual login from a real user. To use this feature from youtube, notifications, you need a user that's subscribed to the channel. 
Your other option is to scrap the channel with https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list every some time and manually compare with the latest check

Comment: Have you got an example for a discord bot?

Comment: why would I? you already got some important clues, follow them down the "yellow brick road": Google/Youtube API, **service keys**, p12 files, push notifications, channels/list. ... connect the dot and make your magic, I'm sure you can do it